# Changing class on click sometimes stuck

Tags: jquery, hover, click

I have this code, and it works what it needs to do but sometimes it stuck (on click doesn't change a class sometimes). Why?
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iznogoud/4ktL83uq)

```
$('#button').hover(function(e) {
  $('.box').css('animation', 'fade-in .3s forwards');
  $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
  $(this).click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
      $(this).removeClass('on');
    } else {
        $('#button').removeClass();
      $(this).addClass('on');
    }
  });
}, function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
    return;
  } else {
    $('.box').css('animation', 'fade-out .3s forwards');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
  };
})
```

Comment: You're adding a new `click` handler on every `mouseenter` event (= first function of `.hover()`). That can't be right... ;)

Comment: Side note; that's a lot of non-dry `$(this)` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're nesting event handlers; the `click` within the `mouseenter` in this case. As such you create another click handler every time something happens to the button.

From the context of the code it looks like you want the 'modal' to hide/show on hover of the button, but to also stay visible when the button is clicked. As such you can add a class to the modal which you can check for and then not hide that element when the relevant event fires.

Also note that you can improve the logic by using CSS classes instead of embedding the CSS rules within the JS logic. Try this:

```js
let $modal = $('.modal');

$('#button').hover(function(e) {
  $modal.addClass('show');
}, function() {
  $modal.not('.on').removeClass('show');
}).on('click', function() {
  $(this).add($modal).toggleClass('on');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#button {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#button.on {
  background-color: #0C0;
}

.modal {
  width: 500px;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}

.modal.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal h1,
p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p id="button">BUTTON</p>
</div>
<div class="modal">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Note that I had to transpose the SCSS to plain old CSS for the snippet to function.